# Converting string into a value

Tags: python

For this code:

```
>>>string = <insert some string here>
>>>for i in list(string):
    j += 1
    eval('v'+str(j)) = i
```

This the expected output:

```
>>>v1  
'a'     #first string's character  
>>>v2  
'b'     #second string's character
```

I'm hoping at least some of you might understand this and help me.

Comment: Why don't you just convert the string to a list?

Comment: I'm unsure what you want. There doesn't seem to be a second string?

Comment: I want to convert string into values, not lists, values.

Comment: Have more confidence in yourself, you aren't stupid (;

Comment: Instead of `eval` try: `exec('v{} = "{}"'.format(j, i))`.

Comment: @XaMi You understand right? `eval` evaluates the expression so you can't assign a value to an evaluation. `exec` on the other hand executes a statement contained within a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice to create variables globally as you are do, try this where `string` is your string:

```
char_variables = {'v{}'.format(a): b for a, b in enumerate(string, 1)}
```

If you really must do this, you can update the dictionary containing global values as seen here:

```
globals().update({'v{}'.format(a): b for a, b in enumerate(string, 1)})
```

Comment: thanks it works, i rly can't admire you enough how you figured it out in like 2 minutes... D: